# zmv for zsh: Dry runs and man pages

Tags: zsh, rename

I've heard great things about `zmv` in `zsh`, and would love to really learn to use it. However, I am still relatively unexperienced in zsh, and have some basic questions:

- Is there is a man page for `zmv` in `zsh` (man zsh outputs "No manual entry for `zmv`")
- Does `zmv` natively allow for dry runs?
- If the answer to the above is no, how would you test or do a dry run with `zmv` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Offline solutions

The [`zmv` manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) is in the `zshcontrib` man page.
You can reach it directly with

```
LESS="$LESS +/^ *zmv *\\[" man zshcontrib
```

(or `LESS="$LESS +/zmv" man zshcontrib` which takes you a few lines further up because `zmv` is mentioned in the description of `zcp`). You can use `man zshall` instead of `man zshcontrib` if the `zshall` man page is available on your system.

If you use Info, you can reach it by running `info zsh` and typing `i` then entering `zmv`.

```
info --index-search=zmv zsh
```

### Online help

The [zsh guide](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide) has a fairly detailed [section on `zmv`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide05.html#l143).
Searching for [`zmv` on this stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=zmv) will turn up several usage examples of varying complexity.

### Tips

You can perform a dry run with `zmv -n` (`-n` is a common way of requesting a dry run).

To benefit from `zmv` and friends, it helps to have code like the following in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload zmv
alias zmv='noglob zmv'
alias zcp='noglob zmv -C'
alias zln='noglob zmv -L'
alias zsy='noglob zmv -Ls'
```

Comment: `man zshcontrib`, `man zshall` and `info zsh` all give empty results for me on Ubuntu with zsh installed. How do I get them?

Comment: @Xerus If you install zsh with the Ubuntu package, you have the man pages. For the info manual, make sure the `zsh-doc` package is installed. If you have the Ubuntu package but not the man pages, there's something wrong with your installation, but it's impossible to know why without way more information. If you'd like help with that, you can ask a question on this site and provide all relevant information: what version of Ubuntu you have, how you installed zsh, what customizations you've made, etc.