# Open man page and search for string in a single command

Tags: linux, search, man

Instead of doing `man chmod` and then `/a+x` to jump to the first section in the chmod man page that mentions `a+x`, I would like to know if there is a way to open the man page to a specific search string, similar to how you can do `vi +string filename.txt` in vi(m).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this trick:

```
man chmod | less +'/a\+x'
```

or

```
man chmod | more +'/a\+x'
```

With a backslash before the `+` sign because what comes after `/` is an [extended regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_extended).

Comment: Cool trick, I did not know that one!

Comment: But now, you do =)

Comment: The `-p` switch obviates the need for the rather ungainly `+/`...

Comment: Pretty nice!  It would be interesting to hear how this works, I thought man already opened less (or whatever pager you have set).  Is this piping less through less with a search initiated or is the pipe replacing the initial man-created instance of less?

Comment: @GreggLeventhal My guess is that `man` changes its behavior when it finds its output is no longer hooked to a `tty` device and most probably spits out plain text to standard output. Compare the formatting in `man man` to that in `man man|less`.

Comment: @JosephR, no it's just that `less` (and most pagers) behaves like `cat` when its output is not a terminal.

Comment: @jasonwryan, the `+cmd` comes from `vi` (I believe) where it also applies, so it's good to know. `+/xxx` is also available in other pagers like `most` or some implementations of `more` like the one found in util-linux

Comment: If `less` is already your man pager, you can also optimise it by running `LESS=+/searched_string man foobar`. That also has the advantage of working with `man -a`

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for the (typically) insightful pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Not as far as I know (but as @sputnick [points](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98110/22222) out, I don't know much), but you can parse it:

```
man chmod | grep -C 5 'a+x'
```

I would recommend using a string that actually exists in the man page though, something like:

```
$ man chmod | grep -C 5 set-user-ID
   traversals.

SETUID AND SETGID BITS
   chmod  clears  the  set-group-ID  bit  of a regular file if the file's group ID does not match the
   user's effective group ID or one of the user's supplementary group IDs, unless the user has appro‐
   priate  privileges.   Additional  restrictions  may cause the set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits of
   MODE or RFILE to be ignored.  This behavior depends on the policy and functionality of the  under‐
   lying chmod system call.  When in doubt, check the underlying system behavior.

   chmod preserves a directory's set-user-ID and set-group-ID bits unless you explicitly specify oth‐
   erwise.  You can set or clear the bits with symbolic modes like u+s and g-s, and you can set  (but
   not clear) the bits with a numeric mode.

RESTRICTED DELETION FLAG OR STICKY BIT
   The  restricted  deletion  flag or sticky bit is a single bit, whose interpretation depends on the
```

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have tested first if a+x is even in that page :)  It was the first thing that came to mind.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you use `less` as the pager (it's the default on modern systems), add the search instructions to the environment variable `LESS`. This is a list of command line options for `less`. You can pass a less command to execute, such as `/` to search, by prefixing the command with `+` (just like with vi).

```
LESS="$LESS +/a\+x" man chmod
```

The advantage over `man chmod | less "+/a\+x"` is that you don't lose the formatting.

See also [zmv for zsh: Dry runs and man pages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19290/zmv-for-zsh-dry-runs-and-man-pages/19291#19291)