# Why is this command to open man page and perform search not working?

Tags: regular-expression, man

This [open-man-page-and-search-for-string-in-a-single-command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98108/open-man-page-and-search-for-string-in-a-single-command) question half covers what I'm trying to do:

> Instead of doing man chmod and then /a+x to jump to the first section
> in the chmod man page that mentions a+x, I would like to know if there
> is a way to open the man page to a specific search string, similar to
> how you can do vi +string filename.txt in vi(m).

The chosen answer was

```
man foobar | less +/searched_string
```

However, when I try

```
man tmux | less +/^format
```

Less launches but returns

> Pattern not found  (press RETURN)

Why is the pattern not being found?

---

OS - Ubuntu 15.10

```
% less --version
less 458 (GNU regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2012 Mark Nudelman
```

Comment: Uh? That does perform a regexp search. All that's missing in your command is the quotes so that the special characters aren't expanded by the shell: `less '+/^\s*format'`

Comment: I edited the accepted answer to make this clearer.

Comment: @Gilles you're right that the search is a regex, however the pattern ` man tmux | less +/^\s*format` doesnt work as intended. What I didnt realise is that the - search as an argument -  method is case sensitive. So yes it is a duplicate,  I didnt realise I was doing it wrong till after I asked - and answered the question!

Comment: Oh. `less` does case-sensitive search by default. But some versions of `man` invoke `less -i` to make search case-insensitive.

Comment: If you edit the question to be about the case insensitivity issue, it wouldn't be a duplicate. But take care not to invalidate Wildcard's answer.

Comment: @Gilles, ah thanks. I wondered if less was using a completely different regex when passing an argument. But your's and cuonglm's comment belowb

Comment: explain it quite well.

Answer (score 1):

Use the environment variable `LESS`, overriding it for the single command you are running.

See also:

```
LESS='+/LESS[[:space:]]*Options' man less
LESS='+/\+cmd' man less
LESS='+/optional variable assignments' man bash
LESS=+/SIMPLE\ COMMAND\ EXPANSION man bash
```

I also discussed this more generally in a Meta post a while back:

- [How can I link people to arbitrarily specific points on a reference page?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3960/135943)

---

There is one thing to keep in mind when creating the search pattern: If you choose a few consecutive words from the middle of a long paragraph, there is a chance that they won't be on the same line when that man page is viewed on a differently sized terminal.  For example, the following works on a fullscreen terminal (on *my* monitor) but not on an 80-column terminal, because the words become split across lines:

```
LESS=+/allowing' a shell script' man bash
```

And because of the way `man` handles word spacing, the following is also unreliable across terminals:

```
LESS=+/"The latest version" man bash
```

The following two commands will get to the same locations, but more portably:

```
LESS=+/^INVOCATION man bash
LESS=+/^BUG man bash
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when launching less and passing a search term as an option, the search will be case sensitive.
Therefore the solution is to use a search pattern using the same case. e.g. these work

```
man tmux | less +/^FORMAT
```

even better - to protect against shell expansion

```
man tmux | less '+/^FORMAT'
```

or alternatively

```
man tmux | less -p '^FORMAT'
```

#### Background

Whenever I used less/man searches were case insensitive, so I expected the same when passing a search argument at invocation.
It seems this is because, the version of man Ubuntu uses, opens less with the `-i` option making searches case insensitive.
So then when less is invoked without this option, you get less' default behaviour and suddenly less' searches become case sensitive.

Comment: See also comments in this question http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127825/38906